# Find child link and remove parent class using jQuery

Tags: php, jquery, list, variables, tabs

**Problem:**

I have a list that consist of two tabs. When I submit a form and the page reloads I would like to track which tab the user was last on in order to activate it again.

**HTML code:**

```
<ul id="myTab" class="nav nav-tabs">
    <li class="active">
        <a href="#participants" data-toggle="tab">Participants</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#gradevalues" data-toggle="tab">Criteria</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

**PHP code:**

The PHP will generate a variable $subtabname that contains "participants" or "gradevalues".

**Scenario:**

If I am on #gradevalues and submit the form, the variable $subtabname will contain "gradevalues". I would jQuery like to remove "active" class from #participants and add it instead to the li for #gradevalues.

**Question:**

How would I with jQuery do to find the  element using this PHP variable and move to it's parent li to remove/add an "active" class?

**[UPDATE]: Non-optimal working jQuery code**

```
$( "#myTab li.active" ).removeClass("active");
$( "#myTab a[href=#'.$subtabname.']" ).parent("li").addClass("active");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the PHP file:

```
<body data-activetab="<?php echo $subtabname ?>">
```

In the jQuery file:

```
(function () {
    var subtabname = $( 'body' ).data( 'activetab' );
    var $activeTab = $( 'a[href="#' + subtabname '"]', 'myTab' ).parent();
    $activeTab.addClass( 'active' ).siblings().addClass( 'active' );
}());
```

---

I've optimized your code a bit:

```
(function ( $ul, active ) {
    $ul.children().removeClass( active );
    $ul.find( 'a[href="#.$subtabname."]' ).parent().removeClass( active );
}( $( '#myTab' ), 'active' ));
```

I pass the class name as a string to avoid code repetition (in your code, the class name string repeats three times). I also reduced the number of DOM queries from two to one.

Btw, if you need the reference to the #myTab element in some other parts of your code, cache it in a variable, and use that variable instead of doing multiple DOM queries for that same element.

Comment: I updated the jQuery code and managed to get it working, but I am not sure if this is the optimal way of writing it? I echo the code out with PHP.

Comment: @kexxcream `"#myTab a[href=#'.$subtabname.']"` - Is this a PHP string? The `.` operator cannot be used for string-concatenation in JavaScript...

Comment: Yes, I echo out the jQuery code with PHP. But I am more curious if there is a more "correct/proper" way of writing my code.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#' + $subtabname).parent().addClass('active');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can return that php variable($tabname) from server side.
Do something like this in javascript:

```
var tabname = "<?php echo $tabname ?>"
// in case if other tab has this class, so remove it first safer side
jQuery('li').removeClass('active');
// add class to that required tab
jQuery('#'+tabname).parent('a').addClass('active');
```